# authenticate_or_request_with_http_token with mailchimp webhooks

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, mailchimp, webhooks

I am using mailchimp webhooks which pings a method in one of my controllers of my application. This method is protected using

```
before_action :restrict_access

def restrict_access
  authenticate_or_request_with_http_token do |token, options|
    token == Crm::Application.config.api_key
  end
end
```

This works perfectly when sending HTTP_AUTHORIZATION=mytoken in the header of the request.

There is no way for me to edit the header of the webhook to include the token. Is there no way to add the token to the url and have authenticate_or_request_with_http_token pick it up?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Kind of disappointing, but in their docs they suggest adding a secret key param in the webhook URL you provide. http://apidocs.mailchimp.com/webhooks/ So you could potentially do that, and add that check to your method.

With the Shopify API webhooks, they actually send a specific header for you to check, and in their docs explain on how best to do it, which I think is more correct.

Comment: Thanks. I ended up just passing the token via query string. Not ideal, but for now I guess it will do.